# Add list-unsubscribe header with Amazon SES

Tags: c#, amazon-ses

I'm searching for an working C# example to add list-unsubscribe header with Amazon SES.

After reading that Amazon-SES now supports adding Headers I was searching for an C# example but was unable to find one.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find [nice API like they have for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29524413/7586). For C#, I found two alternative.

The easiest option is probably to switch to the SMTP interface and .Net's native SMTP classes (or a third-party library): [Send an Email Using SMTP with C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-net.html)
The example code is using the [`MailMessage` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netframework-4.7.1) from `System.Net.Mail`:

```
// Create and build a new MailMessage object
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(FROM,FROMNAME);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
message.Subject = SUBJECT;
message.Body = BODY;
// Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
message.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);
```

Another (less attractive) option is to use [`SendRawEmailRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html). With this API, you have to encode the message along with its headers, attachments, and other data, in a `MemoryStream`.
Example code, from the [AWS SDK .Net documentation - SES - RawMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TSimpleEmailRawMessageNET45.html):

```
var sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient();

var stream = new MemoryStream(
  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("From: johndoe@example.com\n" +
    "To: janedoe@example.com\n" +
    "Subject: You're invited to the meeting\n" +
    "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n" +
    "Please join us Monday at 7:00 PM.")
);

var raw = new RawMessage
{
  Data = stream
};

var to = new List<string>() { "janedoe@example.com" };
var from = "johndoe@example.com";

var request = new SendRawEmailRequest
{
  Destinations = to,
  RawMessage = raw,
  Source = from
};

sesClient.SendRawEmail(request);
```